# How avoid form elements move when get focus

Tags: html, css

I added a style for when input text get focus. Then, all other elements below move every time the textbox gets/loses focus.

```css
input[type=text]:focus {
  border: 3px solid #555;
  outline-offset: 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="CodPostal" name="CodPostal" type="text" value placeholder="focus here">
<br/> text
<br/>
<input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value>
```

I googled it and tried with `outline-offset: 0;` but didn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use box-shadow or outline instead

```css
input[id="CodPostal"]:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #555;
}
/* or */
input[id="Name"]:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #555
}
```

```html
<input id="CodPostal" name="CodPostal" type="text" value>
<br/> text
<br/>
<input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow
>
> The `box-shadow` CSS property adds shadow effects around an element's frame. You can set multiple effects separated by commas. A box shadow is described by X and Y offsets relative to the element, blur and spread radii, and color.

and

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline
>
> The `outline` CSS property is a shorthand to set various outline properties in a single declaration: `outline-style`, `outline-width`, and `outline-color`.

and about outline-offset

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset
>
> The `outline-offset` CSS property sets the amount of space between an outline and the edge or border of an element.